# D3js collapsible tree throwing bad request

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am using the d3js collapsible tree grid to display the nodes and when I run the code in plunker I am getting a weird 400 bad request error.

I have replaced the code which fetches the json and hard coded the json directly like below:

```
var treeData ={"user_id":0,"name":"Root Node","children":[{"user_id":0,"name":"Flossie Hickman","children":[....]}]};

    // Calculate total nodes, max label length
    var totalNodes = 0;
    var maxLabelLength = 0;
    // variables for drag/drop
    var selectedNode = null;
    var draggingNode = null;
    // panning variables
    var panSpeed = 200;
    var panBoundary = 20; // Within 20px from edges will pan when dragging.
    // Misc. variables
    var i = 0;
    var duration = 750;
    var root;
```

[Link to Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pmD1LILsNHaaEI4dADlo?p=preview)

Can you please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: The plunker you linked works like charm. Also, where does it contain the lines you provided above? What is your actual problem?

Comment: @elias the plunker is giving Bad Request error. Please check this link - http://plnkr.co/edit/pmD1LILsNHaaEI4dADlo?p=preview
The code I have mentioned is present in `dndTree.js` script file.

Comment: Are you sure you are linking the project you are talking about? I don't get a bad request error, I don't see a dndTree.js file, and everything is displayed nicely without any problem for me.

Comment: @elias I have now freezed the plunker for you to see. Can you please check it now - http://plnkr.co/edit/pmD1LILsNHaaEI4dADlo?p=preview. ON the console I can see `TypeError: root is undefined`

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't show any error in the console, here is an image to proof:

[image]

Still, nothing will show up. The reason is simple: you are calling your script...

```
<script src="dndTree.js"></script>
```

...before the `<body>`, where you have this div:

```
<div id="tree-container"></div>
```

Which is the div used to create the svg:

```
var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
```

So, this is the correct order:

```
<body>
    <div id="tree-container"></div>
    <script src="dndTree.js"></script>
</body>
```

As a good practice, reference your script at the bottom of the body.

Here is the working plunker (and I emphasise "working"): http://plnkr.co/edit/2aLPBuEXN9f6Tlwekdg5?p=preview

Comment: the plunker you shared is working. Can you please help me understand the parameter responsible for the length and arc of the line between the nodes. I need more curve and less length. I am totally new to D3.js

Comment: As this is a different issue, please make *another* question, explaining the issue and the desired outcome.

Comment: Please find the link for the new question created - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492177/d3-js-collapsible-chart-increasing-the-arc-curve-radius