# D3 js collapsible chart increasing the arc curve radius

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I am new to D3js. I am displaying the json in collapsible tree. The tree is displaying fine but the lines connecting the nodes are mostly straight. How to control the radius of the arc connecting the nodes? Please let me know how to do this in d3js.

The json data that needs to be plotted on d3

```
  var treeData = JSON.parse('{"name":"pradeep","age":40,
      "children": [{
          "name": "naveen",
          "description": 20,
          "children": [{
              "name": "interest",
              "description": "displays the hobbies list",
              "hobby": "S",
              "hobby_name": "singinh"
          }, {
              "name": "profession",
              "description": "describes the profession",
              "profession": "blogger",
              "salary": 20000,
              "children": [{
                  "name": "cars",
                  "description": "car collections",
                  "children": [{
                      "name": "car-collections",
                      "description": "collections of cars",
                      "car_name": "audi",
                      "car_number": "8080"
                  }]
              }]
          }]
      }]
  }');
```

Attached in the working plunker link - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2aLPBuEXN9f6Tlwekdg5?p=preview)

Comment: What do you mean by "mostly straight"? Do you want to increase the vertical separation between "interest" and "profession", is that the issue?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes. Which parameter is responsible for this attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical separation is set by a magic number in your code, there is even a comment on it:

```
var newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 25; // 25 pixels per line
```

You can tweak this value or create a dynamic rule for it.

Here is your plunker using `200`: http://plnkr.co/edit/lmy7R5S6fH3kF69VT9zS?p=preview

Comment: This is looking good. How to reduce the length between the nodes?

Comment: Please, don't ask questions in the comments. In StackOverflow we deal with specific code problems, one problem per question.

Comment: Have posted the question for decreasing the length between the node .Please find the link for the same - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508522/d3js-collapsible-tree-decreasing-the-length-between-nodes