# D3js collapsible tree decreasing the length between nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I am displaying the json in collapsible tree. The tree is displaying fine but the length between the nodes should be reduced. Please let me know how to do this in d3js.

```
 var treeData = {
      "name": "test",
      "description": "sdfdsfdf",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "test",
          "description": "test",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "test",
              "description": "dfdsfdsfdf"
            },
            {
              "name": "truetest",
              "description": "status check",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "variable test",
                  "description": "variable test"
                },
                {
                  "name": "variable test",
                  "description": "variable test"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "uuuu",
              "description": "trest",
              "destination": "10.154.130.1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
        var totalNodes = 0;
        var maxLabelLength = 0;
        // variables for drag/drop
        var selectedNode = null;
        var draggingNode = null;
        // panning variables
        var panSpeed = 200;
        var panBoundary = 20; // Within 20px from edges will pan when dragging.
        // Misc. variables
        var i = 0;
        var duration = 750;
        var root;
```

The plunker link for the same is: http://plnkr.co/edit/uGnQMihoHM1BU1YGPUYv?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

Height and width of links are set on line 355 and in the function on lines 363-368 of dndTree.js file, respectively.

Comment: @Pradeep, did you check the lines I mentioned?